# My iframe is saying The connection was reset

Tags: html, iframe

Any ideas? this is the code I'm using currently.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src='https://www.wallgle.com'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing the opening `<html>` element tag

Comment: yeah, I know, I threw this together in a couple minutes, It doesn't change anything.

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried it in more than that one browser?

Comment: I'm using google, but I tried MS edge as well, the same problem.

Comment: Can you please use the Dev Tools to get the full extent of the error? Is it being reset by the peer